# How to restore the partition layout for GPT disk

Tags: parted

```
parted -ms /dev/sda print > sda.parted
```

This actually copies the layout to a file. If I want to restore the layout, what command should I give?

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's not so straightforward to clone GPT table with `parted` otherwise you would write some simple wrapper which would parse the ouptut of the `parted -ms /dev/sda print` command and prepare related `parted` sub-commands to do it.

But there is available a GPT-aware fdisk tool called `sgdisk` which is part of the `gdisk` package on RHEL/CentOS/Ubuntu distros. With this one, it's easily doable:

```
# clone GPT table from /dev/sda to /dev/sdb
sgdisk -R=/dev/sdb /dev/sda

# make unique its GUID as it was cloned and is identical with /dev/sda
sgdisk -G /dev/sdb
```

Comment: This seems to assume that the two disks are connected and working simultaneously. I get the feeling from the OP's question that the question is about copying the partitioning scheme from one disk to another, by way of a file and possibly separated by time. Could you expand your answer to perhaps indicate how one would do that using sgdisk?

Comment: sudo sgdisk --backup=sda.sgdisk /dev/sda

Comment: Going off the comment added by @hardbyte, this is how you'd restore: `sudo sgdisk --load-backup=sda.sgdisk /dev/sda`